# Compile 64 bit Java program -server vs -d64

Tags: java

I have a 64-bit JVM and I want to run it in server mode with the VM argument `-server`.
I ran across that there is a `-d64` vm flag that tells the vm to run as server.

Can u please tell me the differences between `-server` and `-d64` on 64 bit JVM?

Comment: Sorry I mean 64 Bit in title...

Comment: `-d64` only works on Solaris and it tells the JVM to run in 64-bit mode.  On Windows and Linux, it is always either 32-bit or 64-bit depending on which version you installed.

Answer (score 6):

`-d64` is used in the case where you have both a 32 bit and a 64 bit JVM installed to tell the system which VM to use.  If you only have a 64 bit JVM on your system, it doesn't do anything.  Note that the 64-bit VM doesn't have separate client and server modes, so if you're using it, the `-server` and `-client` arguments do nothing.  So, in summary, if you've only installed a 64-bit VM, all 3 of these arguments are exactly the same, because none of them actually do anything.

Answer (score 0):

From [JavaJEE.com](http://javajee.com/just-in-time-jit-compiler-versions-client-server-and-tiered-jvms):

> ## JIT Compiler versions
>
> There are 3 versions of the JIT compiler, and they are:
>
> A 32-bit client version (-client)
>   A 32-bit server version (-server)
>   A 64-bit server version (-d64)
>   To some extent, you can choose the compiler you want to use by supplying an argument to java (-client, -server or –d64). However different Java binaries (32 bit for Linux, 64 bit for Windows etc.) contain different compilers and may also different behavior for these flags. For instance,
>
> If you have a 64-bit Windows, 64-bit Linux or Mac OS X JVM and specify -client, -server or –d64, the application will use the 64-bit server compiler in all cases.
>   o   Solaris 64-bit is an exception where -client will give 32 bit client, -server will give 32 bit server and –d64 will give 64 bit server, as expected.
>
> If you have a 32-bit Linux, 32-bit Solaris or 32-bit Windows JVM and if you specify –client you get 32-bit client, if you specify –server you will get 32-bit server, and if you specify -d64, you will get an error that the given instance does not support a 64-bit JVM.
>   Now we will see differences between client and server, and then 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: The content of this post is plagiarized from [here](http://javajee.com/just-in-time-jit-compiler-versions-client-server-and-tiered-jvms). I've quoted the copied content and provided a link to the site for you.